# How to Convert Ant Matcher to Spring MVC Matchers?

Tags: java, xml, fortify

I am working with Fortify on my latest project, and have a recommendation to update my pattern matcher from an Ant Matcher for Spring MVC endpoints to MVC request matchers. The actual text of the recommendation is this...

Fortify Recommendation:

To protect Spring MVC endpoints, use the MVC request matcher instead of the Ant matcher.

Every example of the use of MVC matchers is in a Java context, and this file is an XML file, and the lines that Fortify is specifically calling out are formatted like this. I am  not sure what to update or do to get rid of this recommendation and would take any suggestions.

```
<http pattern="/fu.jsp" sfuecurity="none" />
<http pattern="/bar/**" security="none" />
<intercept-url pattern="/fubarLogins" access="allAccess" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved it.

```
 <http auto-config="true" request-matcher="mvc">
 <intercept-url pattern="/fubar.jsp"  />
 </http>
```

It did leave me with an application context error that I had to go about resolving later on.